# Using BeautifulSoup to scrape financial data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data using BeautifulSoup

The code is taking from the this [blog](https://blog.quantinsti.com/quantitative-value-investing-strategy-python/?utm_source=quora&utm_medium=answer_is), however, for some reason the function BeautifulSoup is not working properly.

The code is as follows:

```
# Define The Method To Extract Fundamental Data
def fundamental_metric(soup, metric):
    return soup.find(text=metric).find_next(class_='snapshot-td2').text

def get_fundamental_data(df):
    for symbol in df.index:

        url = ("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" + symbol.lower())
        soup = bs(requests.get(url).content, features='html5lib')
        for m in df.columns:
            try:
                df.loc[symbol, m] = fundamental_metric(soup, m)
            except Exception as e:
                print(symbol, 'not found')
                print(e)
                break
    return df

# Define A List Of Stocks And The Fundamental Metrics

stock_list = ['AMZN', 'GOOG', 'PG', 'KO', 'IBM', 'DG', 'XOM',
              'KO', 'PEP', 'MT', 'NL', 'ALDW', 'DCM', 'GSB', 'LPL']
metric = ['P/B',
          'P/E',
          'Forward P/E',
          'PEG',
          'Debt/Eq',
          'EPS (ttm)',
          'Dividend %',
          'ROE',
          'ROI',
          'EPS Q/Q',
          'Insider Own'
          ]

df = pd.DataFrame(index=stock_list, columns=metric)
df = get_fundamental_data(df)
print("All stocks with fundamental data")
print(df.head())
```

The result I get is that those values on the list are not found, and that the object has no attribute Find_next, but it should not display that. I tried the codes on the list + the website url and it works, but when I put it in python it does not. It shows something like this:

```
AMZN not found
'NoneType' object has no attribute find_next
```

I would much appreciate if you know the reason why BeautifulSoup is not working properly.

Best!

Comment: did you install the bs4 library?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes I did, I did not put that part of the code on the post for simplicity.

Comment: I just tried the code and I also get not found. I think maybe the reason is that the blog post is very old, and meybe the resource you are scraping actually does not exsist anymore.

Comment: hmm no that wasnt the case. The urls still point to the right places.

Comment: It doesn't find the metric thing

Comment: I see it in the html but it doesn't come...

Comment: Ahhh :D I found out what the problem is :)

Comment: Now I am trying to find a solution for you.

Comment: Ok now I have the solution. I am writing it in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the page you are searching on has been updated since the blog post (Mar 12, 2018), and they now require you to have a header in the HTTP GET request you are sending to them

If you don't add the header then they will not give you access to see the HTML

so if you add the header like this

```
...
HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
...
def get_fundamental_data(df):
    for symbol in df.index:

        url = ("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" + symbol.lower())
        soup = bs(requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS).content, features='html5lib')
        ...
```

Then it works and you get the data.